# Pandas Pivot Table Slice Off Level 0 of Index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

Given the following data frame and pivot table:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                 'B':['x','y','z','x','y','z','x','y','z'],
                 'C':['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a'],
                 'D':[7,5,3,4,1,6,5,3,1]})
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'B','C'],aggfunc='sum')
table

            D
A   B   C   
a   x   a   7
        b   4
    y   a   1
        b   5
    z   a   3
b   x   a   5
    y   b   3
    z   a   1
        b   6
```

I want the pivot table exactly how it is, minus index level 0, like this:

```
            D
B   C   
x   a   7
    b   4
y   a   1
    b   5
z   a   3
x   a   5
y   b   3
z   a   1
    b   6
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can selectively drop an index level using [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with param `drop=True`:

```
In [95]:
table.reset_index('A', drop=True)

Out[95]:
     D
B C   
x a  7
  b  4
y a  1
  b  5
z a  3
x a  5
y b  3
z a  1
  b  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use droplevel on index:

`table.index = table.index.droplevel(0)`.